# iOS not capable to install a PWA when not on an exact domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, progressive-web-apps

I have a React PWA application. When I try to install it in Chrome on Mac or in Chrome on Android, it goes smoothly and I don't event see any errors in the DevTools -> Application tab. When on iOS, though, I am not able to install it on any other but one domain (by installing I mean Add to home screen, which should be the "iOS way" of doing things). When it fails to install, I only get a shortcut on my home screen and not the PWA.

Let me give you an example: iOS is able to install the PWA when I enter this domain **something.base.com/sub** into Safari. When I enter in a similar domain **something.base.com/sub/** (notice the trailing slash), the PWA is not able to be installed. When I enter **something.base.com/sub/home**, which is the default route that the app redirects to as an index page, the installation fails too.

Below is my manifest:

```
{
    "short_name": "App",
    "name": "App",
    "description": "PWA app",
    "start_url": "./",
    "scope": "./",
    ...
}
```

And the import in `index.html` looks like this:
`<link rel="manifest" href="./sub/manifest.json?t=<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.now %>">`

The `manifest.json` file is in the same folder along with the `index.html` file and the service worker.

I even tried setting `start_url` as `./sub` but it didn't help.

Am I overlooking something obvious? Or is there some weird behavior in how Safari processes the manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Try with start_url="/sub/"